# Build args are not resolved

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have docker-compose with following code

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./php
      args:
        PHPVERSION: "7.4"
        XDEBUGVERSION: "2.9.1"
```

and I have Dockerfile like that

```bash
ARG PHPVERSION
ARG XDEBUGVERSION

FROM php:${PHPVERSION}-fpm


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && pecl install xdebug-${XDEBUGVERSION} \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

When I try to build php I see that my args are not resolved. For php it is not give me error. It seems that it is just download latest version.
But for xdebug I got error

```
root@Server:# docker-compose up --build
Building php
Step 1/8 : ARG PHPVERSION
Step 2/8 : ARG XDEBUGVERSION
Step 3/8 : FROM php:${PHPVERSION}-fpm
 ---> 876051031ecc
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  && pecl install xdebug-${XDEBUGVERSION}     
....
....
parsePackageName(): "" is neither a valid version nor a valid state in "xdebug-"
invalid package name/package file "xdebug-"
install failed
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y
&& pecl install xdebug-${XDEBUG_VERSION}     
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is explained in this note of the docker-compose documentation:

> Scope of build-args
>
> In your Dockerfile, **if you specify `ARG` before the `FROM` instruction, `ARG` is not available in the build instructions under `FROM`**. If you need an argument to be available in both places, also specify it under the `FROM` instruction. Refer to the [understand how ARGS and FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) interact section in the documentation for usage details.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args, emphasis, mine*</sup>

So the fix is as simple as moving the `ARG XDEBUGVERSION` of your *Dockerfile* below the `FROM`.

```bash
ARG PHPVERSION

FROM php:${PHPVERSION}-fpm

ARG XDEBUGVERSION

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && pecl install xdebug-${XDEBUGVERSION} \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Along with your *docker-compose.yml* and the container is starting as expected.

---

Then to convince you that the PHP image is the right one, you should look at the execution step (here is for my trial):

```
Step 2/4 : FROM php:${PHPVERSION}-fpm
 ---> 8407023453aa
```

Then run the command: `docker images`:

```
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
php                           7.4-fpm             8407023453aa        6 days ago          405MB
```

And if the image ID there does match, then you are sure you have the right image.

Comment: Maybe. But this explains only halfof the issue. Because this is not explain why `FROM php:${PHPVERSION}-fpm` is not resolved

Comment: Well from my test, it is. Mind that the `Step: X/Y` of the output never resolves the value.

Comment: you can debug `RUN echo $XDEBUGVERSION`.

Comment: Anyway I see this in the terminal
`Step 4/10 : RUN echo ${PHPVERSION}
Step 5/10 : RUN echo ${XDEBUGVERSION}`