# Docker ARG null after COPY Command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Are arguments declared with ARG not available after the COPY command?  I keep receiving the error : 'Split-Path : **Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.'**

```
ARG arg_apgs_archive
COPY [ "$arg_apgs_archive", "/" ]
RUN powershell -Command "mkdir apgs; Expand-Archive -Path $(Split-Path $arg_apgs_archive -leaf) -DestinationPath '/APGS'"

ARG arg_generator_template_archive
COPY [ "$arg_generator_template_archive", "/" ]
RUN powershell -Command "mkdir temp/Jobs; Expand-Archive -Path $(Split-Path $arg_generator_template_archive -leaf) -DestinationPath '/temp/Jobs'"
```

Here are my build arguments:

```
'--build-arg BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber) --build-arg arg_apgs_archive=drop/$(Build.BuildId)_APGS_Service.zip --build-arg arg_generator_template_archive=drop/gen-prod.zip'
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing those in at docker build time? Show us the docker build command

Comment: No, they are not. The only thing that could play you a trick is if you state them before your `FROM`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65188587/build-args-are-not-resolved/65189171#65189171

Comment: Added the build arguments. The only other thing I could think of is the way I'm chaining the PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the ARGs are not available within the RUN commnds.  Therefore the reason for the null within the Expand-Archive Path parameter.

Copying the ARG value to and ENV value allowed me to use the value in the powershell command.

```
ARG arg_apgs_archive
ENV apgs_archive = $arg_apgs_archive

COPY [ "$arg_apgs_archive", "/" ]
RUN powershell -Command "mkdir apgs; Expand-Archive -Path $(Split-Path $env:apgs_archive -leaf) -DestinationPath '/APGS'"
```