# Why docker-compose --build-arg not work for yaml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have .bat with arguments, which run docker-compose build

```
...
set "Build=Build"
set "PublishConfig=Debug"
...
docker-compose -f backend.yml --env-file ./.env build --build-arg EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG=%PublishConfig% --build-arg EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY=%Build%
...
```

.env file with variables

```
EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG=Release
EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY=""
```

.yml file

```
version: "3.7"

... 
services:
  customers:
    container_name: emp-customers
    build:
      context: ./../../
      dockerfile: ./ci/local/backend/Dockerfile${EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY}
      target: emp-customers
```

and few Dockerfiles like "DockerfileBuild" and "Dockerfile"

```
ARG EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG=Release

FROM deploy AS emp-customers
COPY Src/Customers/Emp.Customers.WebApi/bin/$EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG/net6.0/linux-x64/publish /app/Emp.Customers.WebApi
```

variable EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG correctly override from .bat,
but variable EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY uses only value from .env

Have any idea, why, and how I can override variable from .bat?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build args are not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65188587/build-args-are-not-resolved)

Comment: no, it's not, He's use variable in dockerfile, it's already work fine for me, but not work in yaml file. I already resolve this problem just set variable in shell/cmd before run docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

***1.** Why docker-compose --build-arg not work for yaml file?*

Build arguments are only accessible on build time.

Compose yaml files defines runtime execution, so, they do not have access to build arguments. But you can use environment variables, that is what your `.env` file do.

***2.** ...how I can override variable from .bat?*

The context here are **environment variables** that are used on compose yaml file or in the container. Environment variables can be passed directly from host environment variables or environment variables command option definitions (`--env-file` or `--env`).

Your `.bat` `set` command creates temporary environment variables that works as host environment variables, that can be overridden by `docker compose` command options (`--env-file` or `--env`).

A good approach is to create different environment files and use them
accordingly through `--env-file` command option.

---

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. What I need - just set EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY in shell or .bat before run "docker-compose" and no need to use --build-arg for runtime variable:

```
...
set "Build=Build" -replace to set "EMP_BUILD_LOCALLY=Build" (it's overriding variable in .env file)
set "PublishConfig=Debug"
...

docker-compose -f backend.yml --env-file ./.env build --build-arg EMP_PUBLISH_CONFIG=%PublishConfig%
...
```

Comment: Why this? Just create multiple `.env` files and call them accordingly or override it with `-e` argument!